# Bored to write app name in every heroku command though I got only 1 app

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Heroku toolbelt is always forcing me to write an app name at the end like this:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE --app [app_name]
```

Is there a way to set the default app to which all my CLI heroku commands will apply?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If heroku is claiming that there are multiple apps in the folder you must have more than one remote in your .git/config.

Remove the extra heroku remote or set the default using `git config heroku.remote remote_name`

Comment: Any solution for non-git apps (e.g. for `container` stack)?

Comment: This did not work for me. I had to remove the git/config lines generated from this and use `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:[heroku-app-1234].git` instead

Answer (score 32):

Going to post this just in case it helps someone else out. I had the same problem even though there was only one app installed. I had to switch my heroku remote url from https to git.

https://git.heroku.com/[heroku-app-1234].git

to

git@heroku.com:[heroku-app-1234].git

Then everything worked normally for myself.

```
git remote remove heroku
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:[heroku-app-1234].git
```

Comment: This worked where as the accepted answer did not

Answer (score 1):

If you have the heroku-accounts plugin installed, switching to the [heroku branch](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts) worked for me, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28292374/2662).

To swap out your existing version of the heroku-accounts plugin, use:

```
heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts.git
```

Note that if you've followed @Moemars answer, you'll need to switch your git remote back to https.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `heroku` from the Git repo linked to your Heroku app, you don't have to specify an app name (unless the repo is connected to multiple apps).

Comment: I'm initiating all commands from my rails app root directory (which is a git repo linked with github and heroku) and that's what it says:
!    Multiple apps in folder and no app specified.
!    Specify app with --app APP.
BTW: I have only one app in dashboard.heroku.com/apps

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the easiest way to fix the issue:

```
heroku git:remote -a <app_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this wasn't mentioned until now:

Apart from the git remote, the Heroku CLI also looks into the `HEROKU_APP` environment variable.

By using [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/), dotenv or similar tools for project-specific environments you can easily set the respective Heroku app for each project or directory.