# Heroku thinks I have more than one app remote, when I don't

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

These are my remotes:

```
Jordans-MacBook-Pro:appname jordan$ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/appname.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/appname.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:jfeldstein/appname.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:jfeldstein/appname.git (push)
```

But when I use the Heroku toolbelt, I get the error that I have more than one app...

```
Jordans-MacBook-appname jordan$ heroku run echo 'hi'
 !    Multiple apps in folder and no app specified.
 !    Specify app with --app APP.
```

I don't get it.

I'm using the "accounts" plugin, if that matters, and have set a default account for this app. But still, only one app here.

Why do I have to specify?

This affects multiple apps on my machine.

Comment: Can you post the content of your `.git/config` file? I guess there is a remote to another app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the accounts plugin has this bug in it you can use this version though https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts