# Does Heroku have any sort of dotfile so you don't have to keep using --application or -a?

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface, config, git-remote, dotfiles

When I run Heroku commands, I'm always running them from the directory of the project I'm working on. So typing `-a appname` is annoying.

From [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555099/bored-to-write-app-name-in-every-heroku-command-though-i-got-only-1-app), it seems like you can set a `heroku` remote and that will handle it.

But instead of setting a `heroku` remote, I would rather use a dotfile `.heroku` where I could set the app and other settings for the Heroku CLI.

So does `Heroku` have any dotfile that I can use to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the git remote, the Heroku CLI also looks into the `HEROKU_APP` environment variable.

By using [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/), `dotenv` or similar tools for project-specific environments you can easily set the respective Heroku app for each project.